# How to optimize jquery script (table creation N rows X 56 cols)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, optimization

Hi I have a jquery scripts that takes table template and adds N rows  (N=[1...100]) as clones of first TR. then each cell in each row is populated with some data (not all cells are always filled), each cell has " on clik " event attached, and on cell hover row, cell, coll is highlighted.

The problem i am facing is the optimization of generation (time) and usability (the mouse movemnts aren't smooth)

the code:

HTML template table:

```html
<table id='schedulerview' class='myGrid'>
      <colgroup id='col_0'></colgroup>
      <colgroup id='col_1'></colgroup>
      <colgroup id='col_2'></colgroup>
      <colgroup id='col_3'></colgroup>
      ....
      <colgroup id='col_55'></colgroup>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>0</th>
          <th>1</th>
          <th>2</th>
          <th>3</th>
          ....
          <th>51</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr id='template' style='display:none'>
          <td id='0' HID='W0_Y_I' class='scheddata'>Week 1</td>
          .....
          <td id='51' HID='W55_Y_I' class='scheddata'>Week 52</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

CSS :

```
.litrow { background-color: #eee; }
.litcell { background-color: yellow; }
```

### file codebehind.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  //turn on row, cell, column highlight on hover

  $("table#schedulerview tbody").on('mouseenter', 'tr', function () {
        $(this).addClass('litrow');
    });
    $("table#schedulerview tbody").on('mouseleave', 'tr', function () {
        $(this).removeClass('litrow');
    });


    $("table#schedulerview tbody").on('mouseenter', 'td', function () {
        $(this).addClass('litcell');
        $("colgroup").eq($(this).index()).addClass("litrow");
    });
    $("table#schedulerview tbody").on('mouseleave', 'td', function () {
        $(this).removeClass('litcell');
        $("colgroup").eq($(this).index()).removeClass("litrow");
    });


    //function for getting data and create schedule table from template table
      getSchedule();

  });
```

### getschedule function:

```
function getSchedule() {

        var data = "{userid:'" + userid + "',year:" + year + "}";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Scheduler.aspx/getSchedule",
        data: data,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (ret) {

            var areas = JSON.parse(ret.d.Areas);

            var schedule = JSON.parse(ret.d.Schedule);

           //remove all rows from table that are not template
            $('table#schedulerview tr.eventSchedule').remove();


           //create  row for each element from DB  - prepare matrix elementsXWeeks
            var $tr = $('#template');

            $.each(areas, function (i, x) {

            var $clone = $tr.clone();    
                $clone.css('display', 'block');
                $clone.attr('id', 'new_row_' + i);
                $clone.addClass('eventSchedule');
                $clone.children('td:first').text(x.AreaName);

                //for each cell in new row 
                $clone.children('td.scheddata').each(function () {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    var HID = $this.attr("HID").replace('_Y_', '_' + year + '_').replace('_I', '_' + x.IDObszaru);
                    $this.attr("HID", HID);

                });

                $tr.before($clone);
            });



            //fill in the matrix with scheduled data
            $.each(schedule, function (i, x) {
                $td = $("table#schedulerview td[HID='" + x.HID + "']");
                $td.addClass(x.Status);

                $td.attr("WeekNum", x.WeekNum);
                $td.attr("PlanID", x.Id);



                $td.parent().addClass('plannedrow');
            });

        },
        error: function (ret) {
            alert(ret.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

The **getSchedule()** function lasts few seconds, is it possible to optimize it so it would be faster?

**CHANGES:**

I've tried different approach for row creation:

```
for (i = 0; i < areas.length; i++) {

            $lasttr = $("table#schedulerview tbody").append("<tr id='new_row_" + i + "' class='eventSchedule' ></tr>");
            $lasttr = $("table#schedulerview tbody tr#new_row_" + i);
            for (j = 0; j < 56; j++) {
                var sclass = "";

                if (j == 0)
                    $lasttr.append("<td>" + areas[i].AreaName + "</td>");
                if (j == 1)
                    $lasttr.append("<td>" + areas[i].AreaSubName + "</td>");
                if (j == 2)
                    $lasttr.append("<td>" + areas[i].AreaParentName + "</td>");

                if (j > 2) {
                    sclass = "'scheddata'";

                    k = j - 2;
                    $lasttr.append("<td class=" + sclass + " HID='W" + k + "_" + year + "_" + areas[i].AreaID + "'></td>");
                }
            }


        }
```

but it's not fast enough- and the problem with hovering remains. (also when using css **:hover** pseudoclass.

Comment: What does the class `litrow` do?

Comment: Could you not use the :hover psudoclass for litcell and litrow, rather than JS mouseovers?

Comment: I am not using the :hover pseudoclass, I am using my own classes litrow, litcol, and add/remove them on mouseover, mouseleave events.

Comment: What do the classes do?

Comment: @Praveen Kumar i;ve added the CSS markup to my post. They just set backgroun-color

Comment: Using the :hover pseudoclass would be cheaper than using Javascript to do the same thing. That's not going to be the cause of your problems, but every little helps!

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like this?

```js
$(function () {
  for (i = 0; i < 56; i++)
    $("thead tr").append("<th>" + (i+1) +"</th>");
  for (i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    $("tbody").append("<tr />");
    for (j = 0; j < 56; j++)
      $("tbody tr:last-child").append("<td>" + ((i+1) + ": " + (j+1)) +"</td>");
  }
});
```

```css
table tr:hover td {background: #99f;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead><tr></tr></thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @Praveeen Kumar iv'e adapted your answer (you can see my edit in first post). unfortunatelly to problem remains. can you look at my adaptation of your code?

Comment: What's the problem now?

Comment: the problem is that the execution is still to long (2-3 secs)